# Running a thread with Tkinter object

Tags: python, multithreading, function, user-interface, tkinter

When I push the button the scan_open_ports start working until the line ip_list.curselection() where it stops, this line blocks the running of the function...
I wanted to know why and how to fix that?
Thanks

```
def scan_open_ports():
    #long runtime function
    print "Asdasd\"
    ip_list.curselection()
def thr_open_ports():
    threading.Thread(target=scan_open_ports).start()
ip_list = Listbox()
scan_ports = Button(window, text="Scan Open Ports", command= thr_open_ports, height = 10, width = 20)
```

Comment: Did you find any suitable code here on stackoverflow?

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with a link to that question/answer and the text of your own code where you say the button is stuck.

Comment: Ok, I think that `tkinter` itself is not multithreaded. To communicate back to `tkinter` I think you will have to use a queue and use some mechanism to poll that queue and do something with it then.

Comment: I tried using queue and it stiil didn't work...
Do you have any better idea than threading?

Comment: Not if you have a function that takes a long time to run and you still need the GUI to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shamelessly stolen some code from this answer, just as a basis for some `tkinter` code: [How to align label, entry in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007295/how-to-align-label-entry-in-tkinter)

The following code adapts this to have a `Queue` and a `Thread` which only runs after a button press.

The `Thread` communicates back to the `mainloop` through the `Queue` which is polled by calls to `root.after()`

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep
from random import randint

root = Tk()

root.geometry("583x591+468+158")
root.title("NOKIA _ANSI Performance")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(background="#dbd8d7")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

Label3 = Label(root)
Label3.configure(text='''Device  IP Address :''')
Label3.pack()
Label5 = Label(root)
Label5.configure(text='''Username :''')
Label5.pack()

Entry5 = Entry(root)
Entry5.pack()
th = None
q = Queue()

def run_me(q):
    sleep(5)
    q.put(randint(1, 99))

def check_queue():
    if not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        Label5.configure(text=str(item))
    root.after(200, check_queue)

def do_thread():
    global th
    th = Thread(target=run_me, args=(q,))
    th.start()

Button1 = Button(root)
Button1.configure(pady="0")
Button1.configure(text='''NEXT''')
Button1.configure(command=do_thread)
Button1.pack()
root.after(200, check_queue)
mainloop()
```

The `mainloop()` is not blocked either by the `Thread` nor by the polling that `check_queue()` does.

Comment: You do have to press the `NEXT` button and wait 5 seconds before seeing the `Username` label change text. I did run the code several times before posting.

Comment: I've just done another test in which I get the `NEXT` button to call `run_me(q)` directly. When I press the button, the whole GUI hangs for 5 seconds while the `sleep(5)` executes. Using a `Thread` works around that.